# QML TableView not calling QAbstractTableModel headerData()-function

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtquick2

I'm currently working with a QML / QtQuick TableView. The data is shown -> great. The only thing I am currently not getting to work, are the headers: As far as I understand the Qt Model concept, the TableView should automatically call the C++ `QAbstractTableModel::headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation, int role)`-function. However, when I add a `qDebug() << "Hello World!"` at the beginning of the function (or using the debugger ;)), this function never gets called and the TableView's header doesn't show any text.

Has anyone got this working? Or is this not implemented (yet?) for some reason (Qt 5.3)? What would the alternatives be?

### EDIT: Additions

#### `mymodel.cpp`

```
QVariant myModel::headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation, int role) const
{
    qDebug() << "Hello World!";
}

[... I left out the implementation of the other functions
 here as they work as expected ...]
```

#### `mymodel.h`

```
#ifndef MYMODEL_H
#define MYMODEL_H

#include <QAbstractTableModel>

#include "inputvectors.h"

class MyModel : public QAbstractTableModel
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MyModel (QObject *parent = 0);
    // InputVectors is just another class I use but it basically
    // contains two `QList`s
    MyModel (InputVectors *inputData, QObject *parent=0);

    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const;
    int columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const;
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const;
    QVariant headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation, int role) const;

protected:
    QHash<int, QByteArray> roleNames() const;

private:
    InputVectors *inputData;
};

#endif // MYMODEL_H
```

#### `main.qml`

```
[...]
TableView {
    id: myTableView
    anchors.fill: parent
    frameVisible: false
    model: controller.getInputVectorsModel()

    TableViewColumn {
        role: "row_line_numbers"
        width: 40
        delegate: Item {
            Text { text: styleData.value; anchors.left:parent.left;anchors.leftMargin: 12}
        }
    }
}
[...]
```

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: Added some code extracts now. Hopefully they help.

Comment: @mozzbozz did you try set data with this method: `setHeaderData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation, const QVariant & value, int role = Qt::EditRole)` ?

Comment: @Chernobyl: No I didn't because I thought that I only would have to implement that function if I had an editable model. Mine however, is static, only initialised once at the beginning. But still the headerData()-function should get called by Qt, shouldn't it?

Comment: Did you find the solution to this? I'm trying to write a similar thing using QML+PyQt with a `TableView` and a custom model (a `QAbstractTableModel` that displays information about regex matches). The only method that seems called by QML is `rowCount` which works find, all the other methods are not called and I have no clue as to why...

Comment: @Bakuriu sorry, but this was so long ago, I really can't remember how and if I solved this problem (or which workaround I used)... :/